# Custom membership provider via WCF authorization question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, authentication, authorization

I've made a global authentication via WCF to use with the most of our systems, but  found that load data via WCF not very so fast.
What I need to do now is verify every time that the page is loading if the user has access granted to that page....
Its a good pratice to go back in WCF request this info for every page that the user access?This will not slow down my entire system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. Common approach here would be to use some sort of "ticket" that you then store as an encrypted cookie. Your local authentication library would validate the ticket and, if happy, not bother reauthenticating via the WCF service.

Comment: Dave do you think that a cookie will be a good solution?
It is safe? And It the authorization rule chage? Maybe cache problems?